# Case Statement Error: an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem with this code is. Before I added the Case statement in the Where clause, the query was working fine, but when I added it in, I'm getting that error. If someone could please help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!!

Here is the case statement

```
CASE 
    WHEN (GETDATE()< '2013-06-30 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE() >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000') THEN 
        CASE WHEN (TargetStartDt >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND TargetStartDt < '2013-06-30 00:00:00.000') THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)')
        END 
    WHEN (GETDATE() < '2013-09-30 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE() >= '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000') THEN 
        CASE WHEN TargetStartDt < '2013-06-30 00:00:00.000' THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Not Filled)')
             WHEN (TargetStartDt >= '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' AND TargetStartDt < '2013-09-30 00:00:00.000') THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)')
        END  
    WHEN GETDATE() < '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()>= '2013-10-01 00:00:00.000' THEN
        CASE WHEN TargetStartDt < '2013-09-30 00:00:00.000' THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Not Filled)')
             WHEN (TargetStartDt >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND TargetStartDt < '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000')  THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)')
        END 
    --ELSE (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Not Filled)')
END
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm sorry about the format, I wasn't able to change it for some reason..

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a *single value*. It can't be used for boolean or control-of-flow logic. Therefore you can't say:

```
THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)'
   OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Not Filled)')
```

You'll need to structure this clause differently. I'm not going to try to reverse engineer your entire query but perhaps instead of nested `CASE` it should be a single one:

```
CASE WHEN (date range checks) AND 
  (JobStatus IN ('Approved', 'Closed(Filled)', 'Closed(Not Filled)')) 
THEN ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to say that if the current date is past a certain set of dates, the data should produce JobStatuses that are Approved, Closed(Filled), and Closed(Not Filled) for that Target Start Date. If the current date falls within the specific Target Start Date, then I only want to show Job Statuses that are Approved or Closed(Filled). Is there a way to do this then? This is for a hiring application by the way, to track applications to a job

Comment: Sorry didn't see the second part of your response. I need the JobStatus to be the end result, as it is in the Where clause and ultimately, I only want to show information for jobs with the specific dates that have those Job Statuses

Comment: I guess I could split it up into 3 cases, each that ends in a different JobStatus = ....... ?

Comment: Yes you are right. This is what something you should do:                 CASE 
    WHEN (GETDATE()< '2013-06-30 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE() >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000') THEN 
        CASE WHEN (TargetStartDt >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND TargetStartDt < '2013-06-30 00:00:00.000') THEN 'Approved' ELSE 'Closed(Filled)' END)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your problem:

```
THEN (JobStatus = 'Approved' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Filled)' OR JobStatus = 'Closed(Not Filled)')
```

This type of clause occurs in a couple places. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the boolean expression shouldn't follow `THEN`